# Image download only after progress bar has finished

Tags: javascript, image, download, onclick, progress-bar

I want to have a link that once it is clicked a progress bar runs for an absurd amount of time, and only after the time in finished dos the image download.

here is my code, as of now the link will click but just downloads the image without waiting for progress bar to finsish, and a minute later the alert happens.

```
<code>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Circle</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link href="" rel="">
<style> 
#prog{
display: none;
}
progress::-moz-progress-bar { background: #cc3399; }
progress::-webkit-progress-bar { background: #cc3399; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="XXX.png" id="ass" download> Associates</a>
<br>
<progress id="prog"></progress>

<script>
var ass = document.getElementById('ass');
var prog = document.getElementById('prog');    
var count = 0;
var target = 60;
function progressIt(){
count++; 
var percentage = count / target;
prog.value = percentage; 

if( count >= target ){
    // **********When degree should download**********
    alert('You Got A Degree!');
} else {
    // fun function again in 1 second ( ie. 1000 ms )
    setTimeout( progressIt, 1000 );
}
}
document.getElementById("ass").onclick = function() {downloadAss()};
function downloadAss() {
progressIt();
}
downloadAss();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the image source first, and wait until the counter finishes to display it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Circle</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link href="" rel="">
        <style> 
            #prog {
                display: none;
            }
            progress::-moz-progress-bar { background: #cc3399; }
            progress::-webkit-progress-bar { background: #cc3399; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="ass"> Associates</a>
        <br>
        <img id="assImg"/>
        <br>
        <progress id="prog"></progress>

        <script>
            var ass = document.getElementById('ass');
            var prog = document.getElementById('prog');  
            var img= document.getElementById('assImg');  
            var count = 0;
            var target = 60;

            function downloadAss(){
                if(count==0) {
                  img.style.display='none';
                  img.src = 'xxx.jpg';
                  prog.style.display='block';
                }

                count++; 
                var percentage = count / target;
                prog.value = percentage; 

                if( count >= target ){
                    // **********When degree should download**********
                    img.style.display='block';
                    alert('You Got A Degree!');
                } else {
                    // fun function again in 1 second ( ie. 1000 ms )
                    setTimeout( downloadAss, 1000 );
                }
            }

            document.getElementById("ass").onclick = function() {downloadAss()};

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: With that code , neither is the <a> tag a download link or the progress bar become visible.

Comment: I didn't test it, I thought you just would get the idea of the changes you need, anyway I updated it, the <a> is not hidden or anything so should be visible.